# VBA - How can I import a List on a website into VBA

Tags: html, vba, html-lists

I am trying to import a list of names and results from a website. The website requires a log on so I have attached the source code below

```
<div class="row reports">
<div class="twelve columns end">
  <h2 class="green section-title">Student completion</h2>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <ul class="inline-list completetion-filter">
      <li>View:</li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter="all" class="selected">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter="completed" class="unselected">Completed</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter="not-completed" class="unselected">Not completed</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter="marked" class="unselected">Marked</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="scroll-list-wrapper scrollable">
    <ol class="filter-list">
                    <li class="not-completed " >
            <span class="number purple"></span>
            <span class="name">
              StudentA                </span>
            <span class="status">
              Awaiting submission                </span>
                          </li>
                        <li class="complete marked" >
            <span class="number purple"></span>
            <span class="name">
              StudentB                </span>
            <span class="status">
              62.5%                </span>
                                <a href="http://members.gcsepod.com/teachers/reports/view_assignment_answers/1995" class="pink">View answers</a>
                              </li>
                        <li class="not-completed " >
            <span class="number purple"></span>
            <span class="name">
              StudentC                 </span>
            <span class="status">
              Awaiting submission                </span>
                          </li>
                        <li class="complete marked" >
            <span class="number purple"></span>
            <span class="name">
              StudentD                </span>
            <span class="status">
              100%                </span>
```

I have tried using outerHTML and things like that but this is never included in the string for some reason. HTML really isn't my forte, if you could give me some help I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

My VBA as requested:

```
Sub getData()
```

Const Hyper As String = "http://members.gcsepod.com/teachers/assignments"

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate ("http://members.gcsepod.com/podauth/login")
Do
    If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
        'ie.Visible = False
        Exit Do
    Else
        DoEvents
    End If
Loop
ie.Visible = True
ie.document.Forms(0).all("username").Value = "****"
ie.document.Forms(0).all("password").Value = "****"
ie.document.Forms(0).submit

Do
    If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
        'ie.Visible = False
        Exit Do
    Else
        DoEvents
    End If
Loop


ie.Navigate ("http://members.gcsepod.com/teachers/assignments")
ie.Visible = True
Do
    If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then
        'ie.Visible = False
        Exit Do
    Else
        DoEvents
    End If
Loop

Const MASK$ = "data-id="
Dim txt As String, i As Long
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://members.gcsepod.com/teachers/assignments", False
    .Send
    txt = .ResponseText
End With
Do
    i = InStr(i + 1, txt, MASK)
    If i = 0 Then Exit Do
    'Debug.Print Val(Mid$(txt, i + Len(MASK), 15))
    Dim idNum(0 To 10) As String
    idNum(0) = Mid(txt, i + 8, 6)
    idCount = 0

    Do While i > 0
        idCount = idCount + 1
        txt = Right(txt, Len(txt) - (i + 8))
        i = InStr(txt, "data-id=")
        'ReDim Preserve idNum(0 To idCount) As String
        idNum(Count) = Mid(peopleData, pos + 8, 4)
    Loop
Loop
```

I have also tried the following:

txt = ie.document.all.tags("ol").Item(0).outerHTML

Comment: Please post your _relevant_ VBA code too...

Comment: I have now attached the VBA code. It logs onto the website then gets the user to choose one of their assessments (Ideally I would like this automated as well but couldn't work out how to get the different options out of the HTML, perhaps I will get it working with some help) and then should cycle through the list of student names and the status and store them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you authorized to access the relevant database(s) at that domain? If you are, it would save a lot of time  if you do it with an Access + SQL Server (or MySQL) solution.

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is a subscription service which we use in the school. Hence why I am stuck trying to use a HTML scraper of some sort.

Comment: OK, that essentially means long lines of code & a lot more coffee. Try this instead: [link](http://goo.gl/R7D5nL) alongwith [link](http://goo.gl/mBu8F). A bit of a effort in the beginning, but once you set it up, it'll be a breeze. Do let us know how it goes.

Comment: The Table Capture doesn't work unfortunately as it is stored as a list and so the App doesn't pick it up as available to download. And as for the Browser Automation it doesn't record me highlighting the list and copying it... not entirely sure what I am meant to do with it to be honest!